# Do I need a separate license file for Content Porter when using Tridion 2013 SP1?

Tags: content-porter-2013, licensing

We've been issued a set of license files by support, including one for the Content Porter. It's not obvious where, if at all we should place this file.

Do we still need this for 2013 SP1, or is it only there in the license files in case you're using an older system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you say, SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 now comes with the Import/Export Webservice as part of the Core Content Manager (CM) installer.

Running the Content Porter 2013 SP1 installer against an Tridion 2013 SP1 Content Manager just makes the `Content Porter` client icon available within the `Tools` menu, and does not install any additional functionality.

[image]

The Import/Export service in Tridion 2013 SP1 is licensed as part of the core Content Manager product.

You will only need your `cp_license.xml` file if you're installing Content Porter 2013 SP1 against an earlier version of Tridion. Supported Tridion Content Manager versions include:

- Tridion 2011 SP1 Hotfix Release 1
- Tridion 2011 SP1 Hotfix Release 2
- Tridion 2013 (GA)
- Tridion 2013 SP1 (See above!)

**Note:** If you only use your (non-Tridion 2013SP1) instance of Content Porter Server to import content items, then you do not require a Content Porter license at all either!