# Content Porter Icon disable in CME SDL Web 8

Tags: web8, content-porter

Content Porter Icon is showing disabled (not clickable), in SDL Web 8 CME GUI.
The problem is same as mentioned in the question [How to use Content Porter on SDL Web 8?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15147/how-to-use-content-porter-on-sdl-web-8).

Although none of suggestions mentioned in above case, is solving my case.
Any suggestions further will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Did you used Internet Explorer to access the Content Manager Explorer interface of SDL Web to install the Content Porter?

Comment: This looks like caching issue, restart the com+ service, IIS and SDL services and then try .

Comment: Did you see my answer here https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/8553/71 about having to install the server-side part of Content Porter? Have you already done that?

Comment: Have you also checked whether your Internet Explorer browser is running in 'Compatibility Mode'? Please note that it should not be! However, this would probably cause bigger UI problems than just the Content Porter icon.

Comment: @Velmurugan, yes I used IE to access the CME interface as instructed in the documentation,

Comment: @Hemkant, yes I did complete server restart, still no luck. Doing once again.

Comment: @Jonathan, yes I have gone through your post. But in my case its SDL Web 8 content porter. Seems no license required. Any further suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: It wasn’t so much the licence that I was questioning, more that the server-side element of Content Porter was definitely installed. Even if it is, you could try re-running the Content Porter (server) installer to repair it.

Comment: @JonathanWilliams, seems issue was related to missing prerequisites which I installed and checked, Content Porter seems working fine. Thanks a lot for all your suggestion.

Comment: Dear all, the issue gets resolved after installing proper prerequisites. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: Excellent. Can you add your fix as an answer (rather than a comment) and accept it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the documentation [Content Porter for SDL Web 8](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web%20Content%20Porter-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-2C77BC74-7C85-488C-A5DC-E779E17D7429&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-2C77BC74-7C85-488C-A5DC-E779E17D7429.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-2C77BC74-7C85-488C-A5DC-E779E17D7429) I found missing prerequisites. Once all the prerequisistes (VC++ 2010 x86, Microsoft.NET 4.5.2) were installed I was able to get the Content Porter Icon and it was working fine.

Comment: Could you please accept your answer so that this question can be closed?

Answer (score -1):

@user2166, try to clear your browser's cache and see if that helps.